# How to upload an existing collection of 3rd-party Jars to a Maven server in Gradle?

Tags: maven, upload, jar, gradle

How can I upload a collection of existing Jars to a Maven repository? The Jars are built from an ANT Task imported to Gradle, and used as a dependency to my task... The Jars don't have version tag, so they should ALL receive the same version number when they are uploaded...

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven' 

version = "6.1.1"
group = "com.oahu" 

ant.importBuild "$projectDir/tools/ant/package.xml" 

uploadArchives(dependsOn: ["oahu-jar", "client-sdk-jar", "common-jar"]) << { 
    // the dependencies will generate "oahu.jar", "oahu_client_sdk.jar", "common.jar" 

    // UPLOAD THE DEPENDENCIES LISTED ABOVE LOCATED AT the subdirectory "build/" 

    description = "Uploads the generated jar ${archivesBaseName}-${version}.jar to ${cn_mvn_serverUrl}" 
    repositories.mavenDeployer { 
       repository(url: "${cn_mvn_releaseUrl}") { 
          authentication(userName: "${cn_mvn_username}", password: "${cn_mvn_password}") 
       } 
    } 
}
```

The tasks "oahu-jar", "client-sdk-jar", "common-jar" are the ones imported from ANT... I have the Maven repositories configuration already working from another project... But the Maven plugin uploads the Jar generated by the Jar task from the Java plugin... Considering the imported ANT tasks generates:

- build.gradle
- src
- build
  |-"oahu.jar"
  |-"oahu_client_sdk.jar"
  |-"common.jar"

The result of this should be the upload of those Jars with the given version...

"oahu-6.1.1.jar", "oahu_client_sdk-6.1.1.jar", "common-6.1.1.jar"... all uploaded to the Maven repository...

Add sourceSets? Configuration? Artifacts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

currently that is not explicitly supported by gradle so you have to do some scripting for that. Based on your snippet above, I've created a sample snippet, that should be easy to adapt:

```
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin:'maven'

import org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.publish.DefaultPublishArtifact

version = "6.1.1"
group = "com.oahu" 

ant.importBuild "$projectDir/tools/ant/package.xml" 

// a list of the ant tasks that create a jar
// I assumed the following convention:
// ant task named "SampleAntJar-jar" creates the jar  "build/SampleAntJar.jar" 
def antJarTasks = ["SampleAntJar-jar", "SecondSampleAntJar-jar"]

artifacts{
    //for each ant task add a defaultpublishArtifact to the archives configuration
    antJarTasks.each{ taskName ->
        def artifactName = taskName - '-jar'
        archives new DefaultPublishArtifact(artifactName, "jar", "jar", null, new            
                       Date(), new File("$buildDir", "${artifactName}.jar"))    
    }
}

uploadArchives(){
    dependsOn: antJarTasks 
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://{'/Users/Rene/.m2/repository/'}")
            antJarTasks.each{ antJarTask ->
                antJarName = antJarTask - "-jar"
                addFilter(antJarName) {artifact, file ->
                    artifact.name == antJarName
                }
                pom(antJarName).artifactId = antJarName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

regards,
René

Comment: If you want to be able to depend on the archives in some other Gradle project, you will want to add the task that creates the given artifact to the `DefaultPublishArtifact`. You would just add an extra argument that specifies `tasks[taskName]` as an extra constructor argument. (That will allow you perhaps to avoid the extra dependsOn for the uploadArchives task.)